# How to test nlu model on multiple requests per second?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, transformer-model, sentence-transformers

I am testing nlu model called LaBSE. I want to know how much gpu memory is required when i run it. Here is example how to run it on sentence and turn it into embeddings:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
sentences = ["This is an example sentence"]

model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/LaBSE')
embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
print(embeddings)
```

It shows that 1.9GB of gpu memory are used. But i want to know how much gpu memory will be used when i run it with 10, 25, 50 requests per second. How could I do that? How could i run model.encode on 25 requests per second for example? I basically want to know how much gpu and RAM memory is required if I deploy it and there will be multiple requests per second.